# How do I theme the user/uid/edit page?

Tags: 7, theming, users

I am using two themes for my web and mobile site. And I'm using the [ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) module.

No matter what I try, the user edit page is always shown as in the theme of my web site and not my mobile site.

The following code doesn't work.

```
function mytheme_theme() {
  $items = array();
   $items['edit_profile_user_profile_form'] = array( 
     'render element' => 'form',  
     'template' => 'templates/user-profile'
   );

   return $items;
}
```

This only lets me theme the user profile page in user-profile.tpl.php. Also page--user--edit.tpl.php does not work.

How should I achieve this?

Comment: are you an Admin when this happens? or does it happen for all authenticated users

Comment: This is happening for all authenticated users..

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this.

The reason for error was that the [ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) module was not overriding and admin pages, by default.
Hence pages like user/uid/edit which are admin by nature are not overriden in their theme and pick the admin appearance theme always.

To bypass this I enabled the THEMEKEY COMPATABILITY Module (Part of Themekey module for D7). Open the following settings page:

```
http://localhost/admin/config/user-interface/themekey/settings/compat
```

Section `Modules>> Integrate Modules in Theme Switching Rule Chain>>`

Then check the option "System (Administration theme)".

Now all admin pages like user/uid/edit also come under theme switching rule and pick the theme as defined.